# ¿Cómo puedo crear una lotería con Phyton + SQL?

Tags: python, mysql

Necesito crear una lotería con 100 números dentro de SQL, los cuales tengo que ir vendiendo y marcando con una "X", además de hacer el correspondiente sorteo con `randint`. ¿Alguna manera de insertar 100 números dentro de SQL y comprobar si hay un número ganador con `randint`?

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo echarle un vistazo al Centro de Ayuda para que puedas leer: ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta? (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Acerca de tu pregunta, es necesario que añadas tu código para poder ayudarte. Para que puedas guiarte, aquí te dejo un enlace para desarrollar una lotería con Python + SQL: https://programmer.help/blogs/5df1e1d38010f.html